# Replace files with specific last modified date with files (or dates) from archive

Tags: files

I had a hard drive nearing capacity (mostly `/home`).  I installed a new larger drive, copied `/home` over to it and went on with my life.

This was on 5/17/2013.  I know it was on 5/17/2013 because I forgot the archive flag when I copied everything, so every file on the server that has not been updated since then is dated 5/17/2013.

I still have the original `/home` directory (`/oldhome`) with the correct last-modified dates.

I need a starting point to write a script that would replace each file in `/home` that is dated 5/17/2013 with the corresponding original file from `/oldhome` (with the proper date intact).  I would only want to replace files dated 5/17/2013, as some files that were present on that date have subsequently been updated and I, of course, want to keep the updated versions of those files.

File count in `/oldhome` is ~63K

Thoughts on where to begin?

EDIT

OK. Based on Theophrastus's comment below (thank you), I can start with:

...from inside `/home`:
`find -type f -newermt 2013-5-17 ! -newermt 2013-5-18 -print0 | xargs -I % -0 rsync -avzI --dry-run /oldhome% /home%`

...which I think might be *almost* there. The output from `find` has a leading period which breaks the path in the rsync command (we get `/oldhome./directory/filename /home./directory/filename.ext` when everything is concatenated. Can I restate `find` statement somehow to leave off the leading period?  The purpose is to identify files in `/home` with the 5/17/2013 date and replace them with a copy from `/oldhome` - there are no files in `/oldhome` dated later than 5/17/2013.

Comment: Regarding "leave off the leading period": Try change `/oldhome% /home%` to `/oldhome/% /home/%` and you should get `/oldhome/./directory/filename`

Comment: @Theophrastus: the find command will run just fine without a starting directory, it will just print the contents of the directory from whence it is run.  I don't want to find files in /oldhome with a date of 5/17/2013... there aren't any.  There are 63K files in /home with that date, though, and I want to replace them all with their properly dated counterparts in /oldhome.

Comment: @hschou: yes, that actually works... somehow.  I'll try it out on a backup data set and see what I didn't think of.